# How to write DISTINCT ON sql in JPQL?

Tags: sql, spring, postgresql, jpql

```
select distinct on (origin, destination) * from datatable;
```

I want to rewrite that sql statement into `JPQL`, so that `spring-batch` `JpaPagingItemReader` can use the query.

But what is the equivalent, especially to `distinct on`?

Comment: does [this](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/select#SELECT_DISTINCT_) help you

Comment: @ankur-singhal: `distinct on` is a Postgres specific feature and works a bit different than the standard `distinct`

Comment: This is one of these fun times where database abstractions come back to bite you. I'd be surprised if it was possible to express `distinct on` in JPQL, since it's not a function, it's a syntax extension to SQL in PostgreSQL.